# Probability of drawing certain hand of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is a deck of 32 cards (not regular playing cards). There are four cards labeled 0, four cards labeled 1, four cards labeled 2, ..., and four cards labeled 7. So there are essentially eight types of cards, with four of each type in the deck.

If you deal these cards in the normal manner (cycling through players) to $n$ players until each player has four cards, **what is the probability that any of the $n$ players has four cards all of the same label?**

(Note $n \leq 8$, otherwise not all players could get 4 cards.)

**What I have tried:**

I thought the answer might be
$$
\frac{8n}{{32 \choose 4}}
$$
because there are ${32 \choose 4}$ possible hands, and there are 8 types of cards to potentially get all of, and any of the $n$ players could get the 4-of-a-kind.

I simulated this using python

```
import random

NTRIALS = 2000000

def sim(n):
    deck = [0] * 32
    for i in range(32):
        deck[i] = i % 8

    random.shuffle(deck)
    players = [[] for x in range(n)]
    for i in range(4 * n):
        players[i % n].append(deck.pop())

    counts = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1, 4):
            if players[i][j] == players[i][0]:
                counts[i] += 1

    if any(c == 3 for c in counts):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    count = [0] * 5
    for n in [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
        for i in range(NTRIALS):
            count[n - 4] += sim(n)

    for i in range(5):
        print("n =", i + 4, ":", count[i] / NTRIALS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with result

```
n = 4 : 0.000889
n = 5 : 0.001087
n = 6 : 0.001288
n = 7 : 0.001569
n = 8 : 0.0017525
```

The values predicted by my formula are

```
n = 4 : 0.0008898
n = 5 : 0.0011124
n = 6 : 0.0013348
n = 7 : 0.0015573
n = 8 : 0.0017798
```

All these values are fairly close, but I'm not sure if my formula is correct. I'd appreciate any help in understanding how to calculate this probability.

Comment: $\frac{8n}{\binom{32}{4}}$ is the *expected number* of four of a kinds (*seen by linearity of expectation and clever usage of indicator random variables*), but it is not going to be the probability of at least one four of a kind.  That these numbers will not be equal is seen easily by noticing that it is *possible* that there are multiple four-of-a-kinds dealt simultaneously.  The probabilities then will be strictly less than those given by your prediction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_n$ be the events that players $1,2,3,\dots,n$ were dealt a four-of-a-kind each respectively.

Counting outcomes instead of probability for the time being, we are trying to count $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n|$

This is by inclusion-exclusion $|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+\dots+|A_n|-|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-\dots |A_{n-1}\cap A_n|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|+\dots\pm |A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n|$

To count $|A_1|$, first pick which number was used for player 1's four-of-a-kind, then choose how to distribute the remaining $4n-4$ cards to the remaining $n-1$ players.  This can be done in $8\cdot \binom{28}{4,4,\dots,4,32-4n} = 8\cdot\frac{28!}{(4!)^{n-1}(32-4n)!}$ ways.  Similarly, this will be the same value for $|A_2|,|A_3|,\dots$

To count $|A_1\cap A_2|$, first pick which number was used for player 1's four-of-a-kind, then pick which number was used for player 2's four-of-a-kind, then choose how to distribute the remaining $4n-8$ cards to the remaining $n-2$ players.  This can be done in $8\cdot 7\cdot \binom{24}{4,4,\dots,4,32-4n}=8\cdot 7\cdot \frac{24!}{(4!)^{n-2}(32-4n)!}$ ways.  Similarly this will be the same for any other intersection of two.

Similar methods count any other number of intersections.

Converting this to a probability, we divide by the number of ways in which the hands can be dealt, which for $n$ players is $\binom{32}{4,4,\dots,4,32-4n}=\frac{32!}{(4!)^n(32-4n)!}$

---

For $n=2$ this is: $(8\binom{28}{4}+8\binom{28}{4}-8\cdot 7)/\binom{32}{4,4,24} \approx 0.00044486276\dots$

For $n=3$ this is: $(3\cdot 8\binom{28}{4,4,20}-3\cdot 8\cdot 7\binom{24}{4}+8\cdot 7\cdot 6)/\binom{32}{4,4,4,20}\approx 0.00066718010\dots$

For $n=4$ this is: $(4\cdot 8\binom{28}{4,4,4,16}-6\cdot 8\cdot 7\binom{24}{4,4,16}+4\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\binom{20}{4}-8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5)/\binom{32}{4,4,4,4,16}\approx 0.000889421466\dots$

In general, for $n$ players:

$$\dfrac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{8!}{(8-k)!}\cdot\frac{(32-4k)!}{(4!)^k(32-4n)!}\right)}{\left(\frac{32!}{(4!)^n(32-4n)!}\right)}$$

---

As mentioned in my comment above, this is a different value than your proposed formula.  Your proposed formula does however count the expected number of four-of-a-kinds seen.  Letting $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots,X_n$ be the indicator random variables denoting whether or not player $1,2,\dots,n$ received a four-of-a-kind respectively, we have $\sum X_i = X$ denotes the random variable counting the total number of four-of-a-kinds dealt.

We can quickly calculate $Pr(X_1=1)=\frac{8}{\binom{32}{4}}$ and so $E[X]=E[\sum x_i]=\sum E[X_i]=\sum Pr(X_i=1)=\sum \frac{8}{\binom{32}{4}}=\frac{8n}{\binom{32}{4}}$

That these are different values follows from

$Pr(X\geq 1)=Pr(X=1)+Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=3)+\dots \color{red}{<}Pr(X=1)+2Pr(X=2)+3Pr(X=3)+\dots = E[X]=\frac{8n}{\binom{32}{4}}$ so we see that the true probability is strictly less than the numbers you calculated.

Comment: This really is excellent, thank you. I have a closely related follow up question: Suppose I am one of the players and I am interested in my probability of getting a four-of-a-kind. Does this still depend on the number of players? Regardless, how do I calculate the probability? Thank you very much

Comment: No, your probability is $|A_1|/\binom{32}{4,4,\dots,4,32-4n}$ using the $|A_1|$ I calculated above, which should wind up simplifying nicely to simply $8/\binom{32}{4}$ which does not depend on the number of players at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the fact that the events are dependent. Simply multiplying by 8n won't lead you to the answer.

For the sake of giving an example, consider n=2.

After the first person takes his cards, what the next person gets will change based on what the first person gets. For example, if the first person gets 1,2,3, and 4, the next person will be less likely to get 4 of the same because there are only 4/(28 C 4) ways he can get what he wants. You can see how this could quickly branch out into a very difficult to calculate problem.

Another issue is that, if the first person picks 1,1,1, and 1, the second person should not even be considered, but your formula will multiply in the second probability anyways.

As more cards are taken, the probabilities will be more and more dependent on others. This explains why the error increases as n increases. For n = 1, there would be no error.

That said, I believe that your solution gives you the correct value for the *expected value* of the answer. This is based off of the idea that probability is linear - https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/ explains this idea very well. However, the expected value of the answer is not what you are looking for - you are looking for the number of times at least one has it, and therefore, if two or more people have it, you are overcalcuating them.

Knowing this, I can easily write out a formula for n=2, simply avoiding doublecounting any cases where both win -

P(2) = (8*2)/(32 C 4) - 8/(32 C 4) * 7/(28 C 4)

However, as n increases, this will very quickly get very messy. I do not know if there is a clean method to solve this problem accurately for larger values of n.